# XSLT transformation -AIF Dynamics AX

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to transform the following XML into a different xml format. 
I have copied the XSLT file I am using for Transformation, however I am getting invalid schema error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="InternalVendGroup.xslt"?>
 <ns0:VendorGroup xmlns:ns0="http://InternalVendorGroup">
   <Header>
     <Fld1>VendGroup1</Fld1>
    <Fld2>VendGroup Description</Fld2>
     <MessageId>{5FC77A8F-67D2-4BF1-A671-FF5A81EF0DDC}</MessageId>
   </Header>
 </ns0:VendorGroup>
```

XSLT transformation code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:InternalSO="http://InternalVendGroup">
  <xsl:template match="InternalSO:AxdVendGroup">
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
      <Header>
        <MessageId>
          <xsl:value-of select="Header/MessageId"/>
        </MessageId>
        <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/VendVendGroupService/create</Action>
      </Header>
      <Body>
        <MessageParts>
          <AxdVendGroup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/VendGroup">
            <VendGroup class="entity">
              <VendGroup>
                <xsl:value-of select="Header/Fld1"/>
              </VendGroup>
              <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="Header/Fld2" />
              </Name>
            </VendGroup>
          </AxdVendGroup>
        </MessageParts>
      </Body>
    </Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After transformation I am getting the following, which not the desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



    VendGroup1

   VendGroup Description

    {5FC77A8F-67D2-4BF1-A671-FF5A81EF0DDC}
```

Why all the tags are missing during the transformation??

Comment: Why all the tags are missing during the transformation??

Comment: Is that your question? If so, edit your post. Or, if that is not your question, please add a question to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why all the tags are missing during the transformation??

Because your template doesn't match anything.

```
<xsl:template match="InternalSO:AxdVendGroup">
```

It doesn't match anything because:

1. There is no element named `AxdVendGroup` in your XML; the correct name is `VendorGroup`;
2. You have bound the `InternalSO:` prefix to the
   `"http://InternalVendGroup"` namespace; but the namespace used by
   your XML input is `"http://InternalVendorGroup"`.

---

Try instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:InternalSO="http://InternalVendorGroup">

<xsl:template match="InternalSO:VendorGroup">
    <!-- the rest of your template -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Caveat:** I haven't examined the actual contents of your template.

Comment: I changed it but still no good.. .<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:InternalSO="http://InternalVendGroup"><xsl:template match="VendorGroup"><Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message"><Header><MessageId><xsl:value-of select="Header/MessageId" /></MessageId><Action>http://schemas.mic

Comment: @Gainster What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: This is my first xslt, I will really helpful if you show with the code snippet.

Comment: `"InternalVendGroup"` is not the same string as `"http://InternalVendorGroup"`. See my edit above.